# Problem calling a trait method of a struct in a vector

Tags: rust, traits

##### What I want to do

The method in this case is `Flower::update`. I need to call update on a `Flower` in this case, in a loop. The loop is in `Garden::update_all()`, and this loop defines `flower` and then tries to call update on that `flower` but does not work.

##### What I have tried but why it hasen't work

I have looked at E0507, and other articles about similar problems. The ones that seem like the might help mention that I need to implement `Copy` on `flowers`, so the vector of `Flower`s, so `Flower` also needs to implement Copy but can't because `the trait 'Copy' may not be implemented for this type`.

Also, the problem is that I don't want to copy the data, I want to call a method on the reference. Like `flower[0].update;` or something similar. I don't need to use the data, only call a method that changes it.

##### What my best guess is

It has something to do with self and it's mutability and how I look through `flowers` and assign a single `Flower` to a variable `flower` and try to call a method on a created mutable reference. But I'm not sure. Should the method have `&mut self` or `&self`? Should the loop make a new `mut flower`, or just a normal `flower`, Should the loop be `&self.flowers` or `self.flowers`. I've tried many variation and I think it might be some combination of these, and an extra thing I don't know about.

```rs
pub trait FlowerTrait {
    fn update(&mut self);
}

pub struct Flower {
   pub number: i32,
}

impl FlowerTrait for Flower {
    fn update(&mut self) {
        self.number += 1;
    }
}

pub trait GardenTrait {
    fn update_all(&mut self);
}

pub struct Garden {
    pub flowers: Vec<Flower>,
}

impl GardenTrait for Garden {
    fn update_all(&mut self) {
        for mut flower in self.flowers {
            flower.update();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut garden: Garden = Garden {
        flowers: Vec::<Flower>::new(),
    };

    garden.update_all();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a better post, you should have included the error message you get.

The problem occurs because a for loop behind the scenes uses the `into_iterator` method from the `IntoIterator` trait, and conversion is *consuming*, i.e., a *move* occurs.

The solution is to iterate over references instead. Simply change your for loop to

```rust
for flower in &mut self.flowers {
  // ...
}
```

Or alternatively

```rust
for flower in self.flowers.iter_mut() { 
  // ...
}
```

That creates an iterator over *references* (borrows) instead.

See here: [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a8aeb4f419e2603d91ec5d5e59562500)

Comment: You don't need parentheses in the first example; `for flower in &mut self.flowers` should work just fine.

Comment: Thanks. I was being extra careful because I thought maybe that way applies the `&mut` only to `self`, but of course the "precedence" of `&` makes it work.